# Hiding Text in ie7

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have this text generated by a javascript plugin.

```
<a class="className">Text</a> 

a.className {
background: url(images/a-image.png) no-repeat;
}
```

But the "Text" shows on top of the image...
Now... with any respectable web browser, I can use `color: rgba(0,0,0,0);` to solve the problem, but IE7 doesn't obey standards of any sort.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
color:transparent;
```

or

```
text-indent:-9999px;
```

or

```
font-size:0px;
```

Comment: i don't think ie7 supports `color:transparent;`

Comment: So what? Just use text-indent:-9999px; or font-size:0px; then.